# How do I install pygame with python 3.8.3?

Tags: python, pygame

I am using python 3.8.3 and Spyder 4 as my editor. I am trying to install pygame but when I execute my program I'm working on, I get this error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'` I have tried using `pip install pygame` and `python -m pip install pygame` in the command window and they all install pygame but for some reason when I execute my program I still get the "no module named 'pygame' " error. Am I doing something wrong here? What should I do to get this working?

Comment: perhaps you are using virtual environment. try install it in your venv too.

Comment: Maybe you could try `pip install -U pygame`? I think you should try installing it in your venv first.

Comment: Are you saying l should install pygame directly into Spyder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment, 6/16/2020, you cannot install the pygame libraries in python 3.8 with pip install pygame, but you can install them with a particular version of them, still for dev.
You can install Python 3.8 in the command line using this version:

```
pip install pygame==2.0.0.dev6
```

Hope you find this helpful

Comment: l tried this but when l execute my program l get the same “module not installed” error. Is there something else l need to do to get this to work?

Comment: I tried using [conda install pygame] in a command window but I got this error: [UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found
to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your environment:

Specifications:

  - pygame -> python[version='2.7.*|3.5.*']

Your python: python=3.7]     Does this mean I have to use python version 3.5.something?

Comment: not sure about it but You have enum34 installed, which requires 2.6-3.5. Installing Python 3.6 is thus not possible without either updating enum34 to see if newer versions support 3.6, removing enum34, or installing Python 3.6 in a new environment.

Comment: I was able to figure it out. I used python v 3.7.7 and checked all the "add to PATH" boxes and somehow that worked. Thanks for the help, though! It was able to point me in the right direction to find a final answer